# how to write unit test function for test whether insert data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, neo4j, phpunit

I want to write unit test function.
Basic functionality of my function is save data to neo4j database.
I want to test that data has been saved using unit test.
Can anyone point me to the path?
pls help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at GraphAware RestTest, which I've just created - we already had a unit-testing support for Java developers that use the database in embedded mode, so adding this was quite simple.

Please follow instruction here: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest

Essentially, you'll be able to send a POST request to the database, specifying its desired state as a Cypher CREATE statement. If the database is in the desired state, you get an OK (200), otherwise you get a 417.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can it be used for php?

Comment: I downloaded neo4j-resttest and there is a instruction to add jar files into plugin folder.I can't find any jar file.can you help me to setup environment for php unit testing.thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, you can download the files from here: http://graphaware.com/downloads/ - get graphaware-server-community-all-2.1.2.X.jar and graphaware-resttest-2.1.2.X.Y.jar

Comment: I put the graphaware-resttest-2.1.2.7.2,graphaware-server-community-all-2.1.2.7 and neo4j-resttest-master to the plugin folder.After restart neo4j I can see REST API.but not REST TEST API.

Comment: You don't need to put the master anywhere. Just the two jar files. Then follow instructions here: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest